# Best approach for rails 3 I18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I have a page with brands, tags, comments and products. It's time to go international
and I have some question about how to setup the I18n.

I have read some about Internalization and even tried the globalize gem
1 year ago but it's still lot of things I don't know how do handle.
I translate the static text on my webpage using the beautiful I18n.translate()
method storing every static and semi-static text in a different .yml file. The problem
comes when try to keep track of relations depending on language.

Before getting into the problem I show you my database-schema/models.
Notice that none of the models has the locale variable yet.

## Models and schema

#### Product

belongs_to :category
 has_many :taggings
 has_many :tags, :through => :taggings
 has_many :comments

- name:string
- description:text
- comments_count:integer

#### Comment

belongs_to :product, :counter_cache => true

- author:string
- comment:text

#### Brand

has_many :products

- name:string

#### Tagging

belongs_to :tag
 belongs_to :product

#### Tag

has_many :taggings
 has_many :products, :through => :taggings

- name:string

## Problems

- **translate fields**
  To translate single fields like tag's name or product's description it's
  possible to use the globalize2 gem with a separate translation table or
  any other gem with the same feature.
- **comments_count**
  The comments_count for products is going to show the total amount
  of comments, not for a specific language.
- **tags/taggings**
  When doing product.first.tags it's going to show all the taggings
  regardless of current locale. One solution for this problem could
  be to put a locale field in the taggings table but I guess there
  is plugins or gems for doing this?
- Brand name is international and doesn't change depending on language.

I need advise from someone who know how to handle I18n applications well and the question is simple: **how do I solve the problems above?** All answers are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I use puret http://github.com/jo/puret for translate data. Nice plugin works well, but I have some not yet solved problems when saving nested models with translated fields.

Other alternatives not working with Rails 3 now.